# Copy always to output directory does not work

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I've got a simple console project where I'm reading two Excel-files. The Excel-files are included in the project ("add existing item") and I've marked them with "Copy to Output Directory". However, they are not copied to the debug-directory when debugging/running the code.

I feel like I've forgotten something trivial. What do I need to do more?

Comment: You haven't got the files open in Excel have you?

Comment: No, I've just checked that. It looks good.

Comment: DO NOT USE "COPY ALWAYS"!!! It will make your builds MUCH slower in Visual Studio. I work on this feature at Microsoft and can say with great confidence that you should always use "Preserve Newest" instead of "Copy Always".

Comment: Changing the Build Action to "Embedded Resource" solved the issue for me. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17688239/439716

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Changes to non-source code files don't cause a rebuild to occur - they aren't considered when the compiler does it's *out of date* checking.

Try forcing a complete rebuild by deleting your output directory completely (sometimes doing this from within Visual Studio isn't complete).

It may be that the files haven't been copied across because a full build hasn't been run.

Comment: It worked for me to `Clean` my solution and then `Rebuild` it. All under the `Build` dropdown menu.

Comment: ten years later still the same problem, thank you very much.

Comment: You should not have to clean or rebuild just to get a build to happen. If that's the case, then the project is misconfigured. Ensure the items you want to copy have the appropriate item type (e.g. `Content`) and have _Copy to Output Directory_ set to _Copy if newer_. Never use _Copy always_ as it will kill your build performance in VS for reasons that are too complex to go into in a comment on SO.

Comment: @DrewNoakes neither "Copy always" or "Copy if newer" (with Build Action = Content) is copying the file on build when the content changes. Only on rebuild (or clean, then build). This makes no sense.

EDIT: Changing the Build Action to "Embedded Resource" solved the problem.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17688239/439716

Answer (score 85):

In the file properties in Visual Studio, set:

**Build action**: None

**Copy to output directory**: Copy always

Comment: This helped me with an icon file.  An icon file's default build action is "Resource".  Setting the file to copy always doesn't seem to work if the build action is "Resource".  It worked when I set the build action to "None".  Thanks.

Comment: the only question remaining is.. **why?!**

Comment: and if the file is in a subfolder in your project, it will be in a subfolder within the bin directory

Comment: Existing project had BMP as a Resource - changing it to NONE fixed it. It is not built it just needed to be in the output directory-Very subtle difference that I missed.this solved it

Comment: This answer is correct if you do not want a re-build if the file changes. If you do need a re-build, then set Build Action to 'Content'.

Answer (score 31):

None of this worked for my WPF project. You need to mark it **Content** + Copy Always.

Refer to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for details on the different Visual Studio file properties.

Comment: Thank you Scott you are Jesus

Answer (score 12):

Did you mark them as content?

Comment: No, but I have now, and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: This fixed it for me (wow, 12 year later)

Comment: This fixed it for me (wow, 13 year later)

Comment: This fixed it for me (wow, 14 year later)

Answer (score 7):

I had an issue when some png files was renamed-excluded-added again to project. It seemed that VS2015 had lost tracking what to do with these files: although in VS the "Copy to output directory: Copy always" was set at the problematic files, CopyToOutputDirectory key was not present in csproj file. I had to change csproj manually from

```xml
<Content Include="xxx.png"/>
```

to this:

```xml
<Content Include="xxx.png">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

Comment: this should be upvoted, I think this covers most of the issues on wrongly copied to output issues, I also encountered this with VS2017

Answer (score 3):

Silly question but are you running in debug mode?  I've made the same mistake and realised I was in release mode.

Comment: Good question, but no, I am running in debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

I put **Content** and **Copy Always** and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and for some reason choosing "Create application without a manifest" under the project's properties finally copied the linked content file to the build directory.

Answer (score 0):

VS 2015 behaves similarly, not updating the output directory correctly with Content files.  **What *does* seem to work,** strangely, is to put a text file in the folder with the Content files and make it a Content file also. The text file will get copied to the directory and so will all the other Content files. Stranger still, if you then delete the text file, it will continue to show up in the output directory even though there is no longer an original to be copied.

Answer (score 0):

VS 2022 almost made me tear out my hair because of this.
I've performed extensive tests with an NLog.config file in a WPF .NET 6.0 project that would not get copied to the output folder even though `copy always` had been set.

Neither `None`, `Content` or `Resource` as build action worked.

The only way I could get it to work as expected was to set the build action to `Embedded resource`. That way, changes to this file triggered a rebuild and thus the file would get copied over.

Comment: Given that this question was posted over a decade ago, and you and I have come across this issue within 10 days of eachother, and your solution fixes my problem, I'm minded to suspect a VS bug

Comment: Tell you what, the issue has been fixed by one of rebooting VS 2022 or updating to 17.8.2 (from something like 17.5, but can't remember and didn't take note before updating)