# File marked as Content -> Copy Always is not being copied

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a file in a folder of my C# VS2010 project marked `Content` and `Always Copy`.

When I change this file and save it, externally to VS, and then run the project, the modified file is not copied to the output.  If I rebuild, then it is.  My guess is that VS does not use the modified date time stamp of the file to determine whether it should be copied or not.

Am I missing something?  It's driving me nuts as I'm losing 5 minutes per run.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you change that properties (Content,Copy Always) at any time when you run?

Comment: Does "run" include build or not?

Comment: Then I think VS skips the build since it doesn't know about the change. Try to create a post build event and copy the file manually.

Comment: @Simon Then,that's normal. The files marked Copy Always will copied every time when its content changed. But its content not changed(rebuilds) at every time when you run project.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan  But that's the point.  I edit the file, outside VS, then debug my project.  The file is not copied.  It is only copied if I rebuild first.

Comment: @Simon,  Ok, because the file isn't open in VS the VS is nothing know about editing of file. Open the file in VS then run project. Do the experiment, edit a file opened in VS by another editor, save then activate VS, it will inform you about editing outside VS and requests to reload.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Yes, if I edit inside VS, it's OK.  I guess VS keeps some kind of "dirty" flag if it's own editors have changed a file.  Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hard to explain so start by getting better diagnostics.  Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, Build and Run settings.  Change the "MSBuild project build output verbosity" setting to Normal.  In that same property page, ensure that the "On Run, when projects are out of date" setting is set to Always build.  Look in the Output window when you press <kbd>F5</kbd> or Build + Build, the *_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory* task is the one that copies the file.

One possible trap when you use Project + Add Existing Item: the IDE makes a copy of the file that you selected.  You might be changing the original file instead of the copy in the project directory.  You'd fix that by clicking the arrow on the Add button in the dialog and selecting "Add As Link".

Comment: Thank you for a detailed response Hans, and the better diagnostics certainly helps. However, it has moved the problem. The file is XML and contains an error. I fix it in my external editor and debug my project. I can see in the output window that the file has copied and the stamps are the same in source and destination. However, my code fails parsing the XML as I would expect with this error. *Without doing anything else*, I rebuild, debug and it works. Edit->Debug fails. Edit->Rebuild->Debug works. I've checked the file copy each time. I'm beginning to suspect some kind of cacheing.

Comment: Actually, I'm confusing myself aren't I.  Since the file is nothing more than content, the file which is read from disk must be out of date.  Since I can see the VS is correctly copying the file, this must be something else.  Thanks anyway Hans and as your answer addressed my initial description of the problem, I'll accept it so that others may see it in the future.

Answer (score 5):

The behavior you are expecting can be achieved by changing the Build Action from "Content" to "Embedded Resource".

Comment: This worked for me.  Marking my GLSL shader files as Embedded Resources instead of Content causes the project to rebuild when a change is made to the GLSL files.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this when I needed to use `COMFileReference` but also needed to copy the DLL to the output folder.

In the end, ending up adding the DLL twice to the project, once as `Content` for the copy to output folder and once as `COMFileReference`. Easiest way I found was to modify the `.csproj` xml directly.