# Getting Location of PDF Resource in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a pdf file that I can't figure out how to get the location of for use as a resource.

The pdf is located in a folder called Documentation in the root of my application and its build action is set to "Resource" and Copy to Output is set to "Copy if Newer." I am trying to access it from the C# code behind of the page Home.xaml, which is located in the Pages folder. The page Home.xaml is used as content on MainWindow.xaml, which is located in the root of the application.

My file structure looks something like this:

- Pages Folder

  - Home.xaml
- Documentation Folder

  - SamplePdf.pdf
- MainWindow.xaml

I've tried using `"../Documentation/SamplePdf.pdf"` or `"pack://application:,,,/Documentation/SamplePdf.pdf"` as suggested in other Stack Overflow questions, but when using either path to create a file stream of the pdf for use as the ItemSource in Syncfusion's WPF PdfViewer control,

```
FileStream quickStartPdfStream = new FileStream("../Documentation/SamplePdf.pdf", FileMode.Open);
```

throws the error

```
"Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Location\ApplicationName\bin\Documentation\SamplePdf.pdf'"
```

The above setup works exactly as expected if I use the full, absolute path of the pdf on my system (`D:\Location\ApplicationName\Documentation\SamplePdf.pdf`) as the first parameter in FileStream. If I use GetFullPath to retrieve the file's path first:

```
  string filePath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("SamplePdf.pdf");
  FileStream quickStartPdfStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
```

filePath's result is:

```
"D:\\Location\\ApplicationName\\bin\\Debug\\SamplePdf.pdf"
```

which I think means the pdf does exist in the output directory as expected, but the FileStream creation still fails with the same error.

Comment: Looks like you are not copying the pdf on build to the output folder. You need to check copy always option to true for that resource. If you see the error, you can see that file path is `bin` folder. Also, `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("SamplePdf.pdf");` this only maps the file to relative folder of the assembly, so if you used `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("RandomFile.pdf");` the result will be `"D:\\Location\\ApplicationName\\bin\\Debug\\RandomPdf.pdf"`. `GetFullPath` does not check if file exists or not. You can try by `File.Exists(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("SamplePdf.pdf"));`

Answer (score 1):

1. Add file to the project
2. Set the `Build Action` to `Content`
3. Set `Copy Always` for output
4. `var file = File.Load(Path.GetFullPath("SamplePdf.pdf"));`

[image]

Done

Comment: Even after changing the Build Action and Copy settings, the pdf still did not appear in the output directory. I manually deleted the bin folders and rebuilt the app, and it still didn't work. What finally did work was an answer from another question about files not copying to the output directory (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495505/copy-always-to-output-directory-does-not-work). I added a blank .txt file to Documentation, set it to Content and Copy Always, and on build both the pdf and the txt file were finally copied.

Comment: @EmilyHerrmann Glad to know that it is working for you. Not sure why steps I described didn't work for you, since I tried them before posting the solution.