# Hosted Blazor having trouble serving file from wwwroot folder

Tags: .net-core, static-files, hosted-blazor-webassembly

I am integrating [Stripe Website](https://stripe.com) into my hosted .NET Core app. Specifically, I need to verify for Apple Pay that I am the site owner. The instructions on the Stripe website tell me to download a file and make it available at https://mywebsite.com/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.

[image: Instructions From Website]

[image: File Manager On Web Host]

[image: Visual Studio Folder]

I can browse to https://mywebsite.com/favicon.jpg and see the icon. But when I try to browse to https://mywebsite.com/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association, I get

[image: Website Results]

What can I do to solve this issue? I have been Googling for a while now, and nothing I have found seem to work for me.

I considered returning the file from a controller endpoint, but the path would include the controller name, so it seems like that would fail. Is there a way to override the controller route?

Comment: Did you remember to set "Copy to Output Directory" to "CopyAlways" so the file is actually getting published ?

Comment: I didn't do that. Let me try that.

Comment: @BrianAndersen, sorry it took so long for me to get back to you. I tried setting Copy to Always, and that didn't help. I noticed that it seems like, since the filename does not have an extension, VS maybe thought the file was a folder. So I moved the file to the bin\Debug folder myself. When I tried to browse to the file locally, it still couldn't find it. I then published the solution to my web host, and it didn't put the folder under the wwwroot folder. Instead it put it at the site root with all of the dll's. I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: @Dawid.Warwick No problem :)

I just did a quick test here. Try changing the "Build Action" to "Embedded Resource" and maybe set "Copy Always" to "Copy if newer" instead. Changing to Embedded Resource worked for me.

Let us know how it goes :)

More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495505/copy-always-to-output-directory-does-not-work

Comment: @BrianAndersen, I tried your suggestion of changing to Embedded Resource, and it still didn't work. But, I did finally accomplish my goal of verifying my domain for Apple Pay. I am going to post an answer to explain what I had to do.

Comment: Good that you got a solution working using a controller, @Dawid.Warwick. I stumbled upon another idea that might work. Try adding an ItemGroup to the .csproj-file with the copy instructions in it.

https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/9036#issuecomment-360831555

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to verify my domain for Apple Pay. I'll explain here.

First of all, this is for https://stripe.com. They want me to verify my domain using their Stripe dashboard rather than verifying directly with Apple. They ask me to download a file, which doesn't have an extension and upload the file to a folder on my IIS webhost. The folder name starts with a period. The folder path and filename are `.well-known\apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association`. Normally on your server project, you would create a wwwroot folder if you don't have one already. Then create the .well-known folder and file inside the `wwwwroot` folder. I set `Copy if Newer` on the file so that VS will copy the file to my Output folder. VS complained that:

`Could not copy the file "C:\Users\user\source\repos\MyRepo\MySolution\Server\wwwroot\.well-known\apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association" to the destination file "bin\Debug\net8.0\wwwroot\.well-known\apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association", because the destination is a folder instead of a file. To copy the source file into a folder, consider using the DestinationFolder parameter instead of DestinationFiles.`. So I copied the file there manually and it worked out. When I published my solution, it copied to the correct folder. But I still could not verify my domain.

So I took what I consider to be the nuclear option. I don't think this is the right way to do it, but it worked for me. I just don't feel like this is the best way to do it. I moved the `.well-known` folder and file to a new folder named `StaticFiles` outside of wwwroot. Then I created a controller named WellKnown.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route(".well-known")]
public class WellKnownController : ControllerBase
{
    public WellKnownController()
    {
        
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        try
        {                
            byte[] content = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(@"StaticFiles\.well-known\apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association");
            
            return File(content, "text/plain", "apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association");
        }
        catch
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the controller route is .www-root and the end-point route is the filename.

If someone has a better way to do it, please let me know.